# How to use the TypeScript Compiler API to type-check modules imported using `require()`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

I am using `TypeChecker` from the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker) in order to extract (inferred) type information for every node in the AST of my program. In particular, I try to find out the return values from imported module functions such as:

```js
var vec3 = require('gl-matrix/vec3')
var myVec = vec3.fromValues(1, 2, 3) // $ExpectedType vec3
```

This works well for modules that were imported using the `import { … } from '…'` statement, but unfortunately, modules that were imported using `require()` like above are not recognized correctly, I only receive the type `any` for them. However, I have set both compiler options `allowJs` and `checkJs`.

**Why are the types form `require()`d modules not inferred correctly?** VS Code (which AFAIK relies on the same API?) is able to infer the types from `require()` statements as well, so I'd guess that in general, tsc is able of handling them. Are there any other compiler options that I need to set differently? Or is this indeed not supported and I need to use some other package for this?

Here is a minimum script to reproduce, I have also put it on repl.it together with two example files: https://replit.com/@LinqLover/typecheck-js

```js
var ts = require("typescript")

// Run `node index.js sample-import.js`` to see the working TypeScript analysis
const files = process.argv[1] != "/run_dir/interp.js" ? process.argv.slice(2) : ["sample-require.js"]
console.log(`Analyzing ${files}:`)
const program = ts.createProgram(files, {
  target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
  module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  allowJs: true,
  checkJs: true
})
const checker = program.getTypeChecker()

for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
  if (!sourceFile.isDeclarationFile) {
      ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, visit)
  }
}

function visit(node) {
  try {
    const type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(node)
    console.log(checker.typeToString(type))
  } catch (e) {
    // EAFP
  }
  ts.forEachChild(node, visit)
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Everything you're doing seems right to me. I think the compiler is just having trouble resolving the module `"gl-matrix/vec3"` as it works fine when doing `require('gl-matrix').vec3`. The language service does resolve the `fromValues` method from the javascript file in the package, so interesting that the compiler API doesn't provide that... maybe there's some different functionality specific for the language service... I have no idea.

Comment: Thank you David, I just noticed this as well.  I filed an issue for TypeScript here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For follow-up, this turned out to be an issue with the type definitions for `gl-matrix`. I should better have tried out multiple packages before suspecting that the TypeScript engine itself could be broken ...

`gl-matrix` issue: https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/issues/429